# pagination in django without using models

Tags: django, pagination

I am trying to do pagination in django. I am not using models. I have a Templateview wherein I will be displaying initial set of data. I just have a get() method in my class to establish connection with MongoDB and get aggregated result.

```
class MYCTargetAnalysisReport(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        context = super(MonthlyYearlyCuringTargetAnalysisReportPageView,
                    self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    .....
        queryset_list = list(db.mycollection.find())
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 1) # Records per page
        queryset = paginator.page(2)
        if request.method == 'GET' and 'q' in request.GET:
                page = str(request.GET.get('page'))
                try:
                    queryset = paginator.page(page)
                except PageNotAnInteger:
                    queryset = paginator.page(1)
                except EmptyPage:
                    queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {"object_list" : queryset}
        return render(request,"reports/MYCTargetAnalysisReport.html",context)
```

For displaying the subsequent pages, I am trying to inherit Templateview to Listview and override the get_queryset() method. But this doesn't work well.

Comment: Specify error you are facing. Add error trace or give more details.

Comment: Why do you need a separate view for subsequent pages, instead of just passing the page number into the `paginator.page` call in this one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I tried that; but then it executes the db query again for each page which will be costly. I want to do a single fetch of all records and then display it in multiple pages.